# How to select edges of the mesh's boundary

Tags: mesh, bevel

Is it possible to select all the edges of a mesh outlines(boundaries)? I tried in edit mode with "Select > Select Loops > Select Boundary Loop" but it seems to not select anything.

I'm trying to bevel all outlines of a mesh at once to have same bevel everywhere.

I'm using Blender 3.1.

Comment: That tool works with the selected edges, so select something (may be all of the mesh) before use it.

Comment: Same, it select nothing at all

Comment: What do you mean by "outline"? Do you have a closed 3D object like the default cube or a 2D plane? Select Boundary Loop does this => https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html#bpy-ops-mesh-region-to-loop

Comment: By outlines, im talking about the edges that make the mesh's shape. Like selecting only the edges without subdivisions.

Answer (score 0):

ADD BEVEL MODIFIER IN THE MODIFIER PANNEL AND ADJUST THE AMOUNT VALUE UNTIL YOU ARE SATISFIED.. you can bevel all edges without selecting it[image]

Comment: That's the point I don't want. I need to bevel all edges that make the closed mesh's shape without having to select all and unselect subdivisions edges.